# Linked-List Returns Empty List

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I'm inserting nodes at the head of a Linked-List, and printing each node using a print() method.

Each node consists of two (2) strings and one (1) int.

The Linked-List insertion seems to work as intended. However, nothing is being print or shown from the Linked-List when debugging the code.

Can anyone find why the Linked-List isn't showing any data or being printed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Node
{
    public:
        std::string name;
        std::string ipaddress;
        int iD;
        Node* next = NULL;

        Node(std::string name, std::string ipaddress, int iD)
        {
            this->name = name;
            this->ipaddress = ipaddress;
            this->iD = iD;
        }
};

class OfficeSpace
{
    public:
        Node* head = NULL;

        void insert (std::string name, std::string ipaddress, int iD)
        {
            Node* node = new Node(name, ipaddress, iD);
            node->next = head;
            head = node->next;
        }

        void print()
        {
            Node* temp = head;
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                std::cout << temp->name << std::endl << temp->ipaddress << 
                    "iD: " << temp->iD << std::endl;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    OfficeSpace office;

    office.insert("Peter", "20.3.45.7", 22422);
    office.insert("Samir", "20.3.45.2", 25233);
    office.insert("Lawrence", "20.3.44.10", 27465);
    office.insert("Joanna", "20.3.44.8", 24544);
    office.insert("Bill Lumbergh", "20.3.44.12", 22445);
    office.insert("Tom Smykowski", "20.3.35.4", 26464);
    office.insert("Milton", "20.3.35.9", 24645);

    office.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried passing the expected variables into the office.insert(..) method, but I experienced the same problem.

Comment: I highly recommend using a debugger and drawing links and nodes.  You can be running  your debugger while people are reviewing and running debuggers on your code.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `this->` syntax, except to differentiate between parameter names and member names.  If you change your coding style so member names or parameter names are different, you don't need the `this->`.  For example, prefix member names with `m_`.

Comment: I have a couple general design suggestions. An office space is an office space. A list is a list. You may need a list to utilize your office space.  Or office space could be the name of a list. But an office space is not a list. And the Node is an implementation detail that shouldn't be globally available. The Node is also too specialized. The Node is just a container for the purpose of the linked list. It's not *also* the data.

Comment: you don't need to use `this->` syntax. You can still use same names pour parameters and members. You can write the constructor with an initialisation list. `Node(std::string name, std::string ipaddress, int iD) : name(std::move(name),ipaddress(std::move(ipadress),iD{iD} {}`.

Answer (score 5):

In these lines of `OfficeSpace::insert`:

```cpp
            node->next = head;
            head = node->next;
```

You firstly set `node->next` to `head` (`NULL`), then set `head` to `node->next` (set to `NULL` in the line just before).

The fix is:

```cpp
            node->next = head;
            head = node;
```

Instead of `node->next`, you should assign `node` to the variable `head`.